# Good solution for AWS ElasticBeanstalk Container dying due to Docker Pool Size

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I got the issue where Docker is reaching the Pool Size limit, which is 100% of the disk (12Gb). I had a cronjob running this command as suggested by aws:

```
sudo docker ps -q | xargs sudo docker inspect --format='{{ .State.Pid }}' | xargs -IZ sudo fstrim /proc/Z/root/"
```

But I need a better solution since this one is not being robust enough, aws also suggest in here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html to add a second disk for your application.

What I want to do, is only add an ephemeal disk to the container /tmp which is the place my application is adding/removing loads of files.

I am finding it tricky to setup the .ebextensions file since it is all default configuration to EB and I need to make sure the current setup is not changed. I started using this format but I am not sure if the mapping is right.

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    BlockDeviceMappings: /dev/xvda=:16:true:gp2,/dev/xvdcz=:12:true:gp2,/dev/sdh=:12:true:gp2
```

How can I make sure the this is right? how to setup and map /tmp folder of my container?

Here is my environment:

So, for what I can see on aws panel I have two SSD disks attached to the provisioned EC2.

```
/dev/xvda   16GB gp2 100IOPS
/dev/xvdz   12GB gp2 100IOPS
```

Looking at the df it show that I have a disk with 100GB which I do not know where it is coming from.

When I log into the EC2, it is showing this:

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.9G   84K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       16G  1.8G   14G  12% /
```

The mount is like this:

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1918844k,nr_inodes=479711,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
/dev/xvda1 on /var/lib/docker/plugins type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/xvda1 on /var/lib/docker/devicemapper type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-524315-c2f6bc2b0afd5c8fa3e5ea2a230d20a7b29b5949a9c43211f87285111970212e on /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c2f6bc2b0afd5c8fa3e5ea2a230d20a7b29b5949a9c43211f87285111970212e type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=128,data=ordered)
shm on /var/lib/docker/containers/e0a908391b776bcbef403f411c031ab9d0cc48fb0aa05c178c41598042cf956e/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=65536k)
nsfs on /var/run/docker/netns/1b779e66ebaa type nsfs (rw)
```

lvs output:

```
    [ec2-user@ ~]$ sudo lvs
      LV          VG     Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
      docker-pool docker twi-aot--- 11.96g             20.04  3.44
```

Docker inspect shows:

```
},
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "DeviceId": "68",
                "DeviceName": "docker-202:1-524315-c2f6bc2b0afd5c8fa3e5ea2a230d20a7b29b5949a9c43211f87285111970212e",
                "DeviceSize": "107374182400"
            },
            "Name": "devicemapper"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app",
                "Destination": "/var/log/worker",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

If I log into my container I see the following map.

```
root@e0a908391b77:/# df -h
Filesystem                                                                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-524315-c2f6bc2b0afd5c8fa3e5ea2a230d20a7b29b5949a9c43211f87285111970212e   99G  594M   93G   1% /
tmpfs                                                                                              64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1                                                                                         16G  1.8G   14G  12% /etc/hosts
shm                                                                                                64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                                             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                                                                             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/firmware
```